# Why can't Visual Studio 2010 C# Express format nested code correctly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, format, code-formatting

Consider this code...

```
Create(x,y,z,
null, null, null,
new Class1[     ] {
    new Class1(a,b,c),
    new Class1(a,b,c)
},
new Class2[] {
    new Class2(d,e,f    )
},
true);
```

Notice the lack of spacing after the parameter commas, and the extra spacing in the Class1 array definition and Class2 call.

If I format my document -- Ctrl+E, D or Ctrl+K, D -- the code is formatted to this...

```
Create(x, y, z,
null, null, null,
new Class1[] {
    new Class1(a,b,c),
    new Class1(a,b,c)
},
new Class2[] {
    new Class2(d,e,f    )
},
true);
```

Notice that the parameter commas in the "outer" code have been properly formatted with spaces (according to my preferences), and the extra spaces have been removed from the Class1 array definition (again, my preferences). However, the parameter commas in the "inner" code HAVE NOT been correctly formatted and the extra spacing remains in the Class2 call.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code -- it compiles and runs without errors.

This happens every time I create nested, complex calls using braces. I suppose I could just make my code longer and more complex by breaking it all apart and using temporary variables but that seems like overkill.

Why can't Visual Studio 2010 C# Express correctly format such nested code?
Has anyone else experienced this?
I can provide my Formatting preferences if necessary.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (VS 2010 Pro). It works though, if you have `new Class1[] { new Class1(a,b,c), new Class1(a,b,c) }` on the same line.

Comment: I kinda wanted to try in VS2012, and you can call me lazy for this, but could you add your class and function definitions so I can just paste it and see how it formats?

Comment: I honestly don't see the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Look at the SPACES before and after formatting the document. If necessary, copy-and-paste the code into Notepad to see the differences.

Comment: @Gray -- these are just generic classes and methods for the sake of the question. (I don't want to post my real code but it's basically the same structure.) Here's the definition for Class1; Class2 and Create are similar. 

class Class1
{
 int A, B, C;
 public Class1(int a, int b, int c)
 {
  A = a;
  B = b;
  C = c;
 }
}

(sorry -- the comments editor runs it all on the same line)

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue (as is everyone, i suspect)

Comment: After lots of experimentation, it appears this may be a Feature after all...

This allows you to create (for example) a Dictionary with spacing/alignment for readability.
You can create your own "columns" of data that will remain where you position them, even after your format the document.

Whether or not you want this is a matter of personal preference.

I can see the value of both ways, although I think most people would prefer auto-formatting as opposed to manual formatting.

Answer (score 1):

@tvwxyz: I could reproduce this issue with Ctrl+K, D.

But, interestingly if I enable "Automatically format completed block on }" it works fine (gets intended as expected) when I close the function.

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor-> C#-> Formatting -> General ->
>   Automatically format completed block on }